# How to use an index with list view threshold

Tags: list, filter, list-view-threshold

I have a list with 20,000 records that I have been trying to deal with. Threshold is at the default 5k.

I was under the impression that if I index a column, filter on it, and my results are under 5k, I should be able to see everything. I have an indexed "status" column. I have 51 records with status pending. My filter says show only items when status = pending.

On my view I'm getting the dreaded "Displaying only the newest results below. To view all results, narrow your query by adding a filter." And I see 2 results.

If I login under admin account (with it's higher threshold), I correctly see 51 results.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read about indexes possibly not being able to build due to list threshold, but don't think this was the problem. I saw no errors building and was still under the admin threshold. Filtering on index with CAML on custom dataview web part worked fine, but list views still would not work.

I gave up and changed the threshold to 25k for user and 30k for admin. Feels like a dirty fix, but I don't know what else to do. I may try changing it back down in a few days to see if it was a case of indexes not building. I haven't noticed any performance issues yet, but will update this if I do.

Also it took a while for threshold to drop off. Didn't have to change anything, just waited a while (maybe 15-20 minutes?)

Answer (score 1):

Chris,

Your impression is correct.

If you **index** a column, **filter** on it, and if the results returned are **less than or equal to** the list view threshold (5000), then you will be able to see the results returned by the query.

The only reasons I can think of for this not work would be:

- You are **filtering on other columns** that are not indexed.
- You are **grouping the items** by a column. I am not sure how the grouping works when the list view threshold has been exceeded, but still try to remove any "Group By" options.

Comment: My column was indexed and showed as indexed both on the view on under indices section of list settings. Result set was only 51 records. There was no grouping. Just a classic case of sharepoint not working I guess. No problems after changing threshold and no noticeable performance issues so far. I do wish the advertised solution had worked though.

Comment: I see. What I would try is to create a view with a filter on the ID column as that is always indexed by default. Make something like "ID less than 5000" and you should be able to get all items with an ID lower than 5000. I mean such a view should work, and if it doesn't, there are probably other problems going on in your SharePoint farm. I also recommend you to create a folder for each "Status" you have. Folders are another solution to get around the list view threshold and also keep items organised. The threshold should always be 5000 for users. There are very few exceptions for changing it.

Comment: ID test is a good one. I will change threshold back and try that (when I get more time). I have been trying to come up with good ways to group data into smaller subsets and create folders for these as well. Thanks for your help.